# Cast a quickened spell as a standard action

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, actions, metamagic

As a prepared caster, are you able to cast a quickened spell using a standard action instead of a swift action? I know a move action is not allowed to be converted into a swift action.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cannot. The only form of action trading in the game is standard→move (and swift→immediate or move+standard→full-round but those are different). You cannot use a standard action (or move action) to get another swift action.

> In a normal round, you can perform a standard action and a move action, or you can perform a full-round action. You can also perform one swift action and one or more free actions. **You can always take a move action in place of a standard action.**

Note that this is the only case mentioned by the rules.

One of the (few) drawbacks of prepared spellcasters is that metamagic has to be applied ahead of time, and once applied, it is not optional.

Comment: You can improve the answer quoting that part of the rules that say you can only use "a single swift action per turn" and only one. From a balance point, it risks opening the possibility of multiple uses of the same ability in a single turn and break the system on some cases.

Comment: @Balacertar I *did* quote that part of the rules: “In a normal round, you can perform [...] one swift action.”

Comment: I was referring to this more specific entry about swift action: http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/combat.html#swift-action

Comment: So, I need to be very careful about making sure I have non-quickened spells to cast. Thanks